# Try catch equivalent in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, plpgsql, error-handling

Do we have a try catch equivalent in Postgres? I have written some user defined functions that are called by trigger. I (don't) want to ignore errors so that flow does not get interrupted.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The equivalent of TRY-CATCH error handling in PostgreSQL is a block of code in this way:

```
[ <<label>> ]
[ DECLARE
    declarations ]
BEGIN
    statements
EXCEPTION
    WHEN condition [ OR condition ... ] THEN
        handler_statements
    [ WHEN condition [ OR condition ... ] THEN
          handler_statements
      ... ]
END;
```

Have a look at Postgres docs about [Trapping errors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

If you want to use it in your functions, keep in mind it can only be used inside PL/pgSQL functions.